# How do you transfer an array from class to class in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone

As one might expect I'm new to Objective-C and Cocoa2d so this might be painfully obvious but I can't seem to get it to work in a way that makes sense.

What I'm trying to do is to make an array of 10 members (more will be added later) full of either [0,1,2,3] integers, later I want these numbers to be used for a level selection screen where 0 means the level is locked (not completed), and the numbers >0 represent the number of stars (out of three) and mean the level was completed, at the end of a level I want to change the array to reflect that the level was completed. For testing purposes I filled the array with "random integers" (0-3) as such (in `LevelSelection.m`):

```
NSMutableArray *LevelCompArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            int x= (arc4random() % (4));
            [LevelCompArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:x]];
        }
```

I have not alloced nor init the Array but it seems to work within the function itself `-(id) init` though I believe that is a the root of my problem.

My problem is simple, how do I transfer this array (and other data I will create as my game progresses) from class to class (e.g. from `LevelSelection.m` to `LevelCompleted.m`) and from function to function (e.g. `-(id) init` and `-(void) launchLevel`). Do I have a centralized file for data that all required classes can access? If that's the case what's with all the talk of a ".plist"? If not, do I transfer the data through methods to the target class(es)/ method(s)? How do I do that?

Any help is deeply appreciated, transferring me to a tutorial would also be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be, as you said, have a bunch of global variables in a file that everyone `#import`s. You wouldn't use a `.plist` file; rather, it would just be a `.m` like all your other source code.

You could also pass the information to the constructor of any object that needs it. For example, you could do something like `[[LevelSelection alloc] initWithCompletionArray:LevelCompArray]`. Then, to make sure that every object has the right information in said array, use notifications.

```
-(id) initWithStuff:(Stuff *s) {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(doStuff:)
                                                     name:@"LEVEL_COMPLETED"
                                                   object:anObject];
    }
```

And then in `doStuff:` (which takes an `NSNotification*`), you'd have some logic to handle whatever happened, using the notification's object.

Answer (score 2):

you shoukld use a property for the array. like that:
first you need to create the array in the secondviewcontroller.h, like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *LevelCompArray;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *LevelCompArray;
```

then synthesize it in the secondviewcontroller.m:

```
@synthesize LevelCompArray;
```

Then, for example, you want to pass Array when a button in FirstViewController is touched. In its action, you can set it to get the instance of your second view controller, like that:

```
secondViewController.LevelCompArray = someArray;
```

actually it is passing data between viewcontroller, for more info check this link:
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

hope this help.

Comment: You don't need that first line "NSMutableArray *LevelCompArray;" in your first code sample.